# Temporary 'loading' route in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a web app that takes a moment to load - as it needs to connect to a database, and so some other things that take time.

What's the best way to have a temporary loading route in Express?

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// Temporary / for if someone hits the server before it's finished starting
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(`Loading....`))

// In my non-demo app, there's a router here that takes a moment to load, instead of a timeout. 
setTimeout(function(){
  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(`Ready!`))
}, 3 * 1000)

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Comment: On your front end I would just check `if (data is not yet available)` show `Loading...` and when it becomes available then show the data. No need for another route and timeouts

Comment: If you are trying to push `Ready!` to the client you can't do that without sockets.

Comment: @VincentNguyen my back end (the route for /) takes a while to load, so if I have any front end at all, the route has loaded.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be connecting to the database on every request. You should connect when the server starts and have a constantly open connection.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Not trying to push 'Ready' (if I was, I'd use SSE) just to show something for people (probably other devs) who hit / before / is ready.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn The router for / needs the database to start. I'm not connecting to the database on every request - I'm not sure where you got this impression.

Comment: @mikemaccana the first paragraph makes it sound like that, everything should already be loaded at the time the user makes the request, and since you said that you "need to load things" I assumed that you were loading on every request (if that makes sense).

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn it takes a moment to load on the server. As the web server needs to connect to the database, various APIs etc. From the client to the server it responds pretty quickly.

Comment: We don't understand why the visitor would be visiting your site before the server starts? Once the server starts and is connected to the database and API...then you can visit the site seamlessly. What is the problem exactly? You start the server once and then visitors come.

Comment: @VincentNguyen Because they're a web developer and they're not  used to apps that take 20 seconds to start.

Comment: @VincentNguyen If I'v answered all your question, could you mod the question back up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes [can't be deleted at runtime](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2596), but you can add a middleware that checks if everything is initialized, if it isn't you end the request with: `res.send('Loading');` otherwise you go to the next middelware.

```
let initialized = false;

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if(!initialized)
       return res.send('Loading...');
    next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(`Ready!`);
});

setTimeout(() => initialized = true, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's more than just a DB, there's a few API clients that need to be started, some health checks etc.

Comment: Well, you can use my approach anyway, just add the middleware that check for everything to be initialized.

Comment: Thanks @marcos, I've made a couple of minor tweaks to the variable namin but this sounds like the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your app needs some time to load properly, the best option is to NOT let it start the server.

It works very well with i.e. load balancers and multiple containers as they wait for the /health check to pass before they put the container behind the loadbalancer. Which is something you want to do for modern services.

For example this:

```
import { app } from './app';
import { config } from './config';
import { logger } from './components/ourLog';
import { initPromise } from './components/ourMongo';

const port = config.server.port;

async function startServer() {
    await initPromise;
    app.listen(port, () => {
        logger.info(
            {
                port,
                params: config.params,
                processEnv: process.env,
            },
            'App has started'
        );
    });
}

startServer()
    .catch(err => {
        logger.error({ err }, 'Critical error, cannot start server');
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

We have component that connects to mongo and it expose `initPromise`, which is the promise, which is resolved after the connection is sucesfully done and you can start with using the db.

Comment: Already checking for health in production LB. Already waiting to listen on the port until the app has finished starting. I want to be able to show something to a developer who's started his browser and tried to load the app before his local server has finished starting.

Comment: @mikemaccana - Well thats the problem, you check for /health in LB, it says "yay, I can do work" and then service says "I am not started yet". If you do not call `app.listen`, you do not expose server and /health does not pass. Which means the LB will wait and try again later to call the /health. And if you start the server after you load everything /health pass as well, it gets behind LB and all developers/users will always hit only working service and dont have to handle any `pending` status.

Comment: I'm not talking about production, except in response to your question. I'm talking about showing something useful if a dev hits their local webserver, or there's a catastrophic failure and 0 servers are available. I have a health check in production LB, when it says "yay, I can do work" it can. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @mikemaccana - Well you should never put dev local webserver code into the production one. Also if it is deployed on his machine/by him, the log `App has started` is enough, also he should be able to see if it terminates or not. If it is deployed somewhere, to be really useful, it should imitate the production as close as possible.

Comment: "Well you should never put dev local webserver code into the production one" how do you expect to develop software if you don't use the same code in production and on your dev webserver? I have an "App is ready". Not everyone reads every console message.

Comment: @mikemaccana - I mean you should never create only dev-specific code in your app as the same code will run on prod. Like shaping the code because of development issues. I still dont understand full use-case. I run the server, I can see if it terminates or not. When I start the local server there is no traffic right? So if the last log is app started, then the app started, otherwise not. Its not about reading every console message

Comment: It's a single conditional ‍♂️ Since I already have a `console.log('App is ready')` and this isn't the question I asked I've downmodded it.

Answer (score -1):

You could ping the server "x" seconds to test when it is ready.

### Server

We will create a `ready` variable, that is set to `false`, when all of your database, api and other things are done doing what they need you set it to `true`.

We will also create a route that such as `/ping` that will respond with the value of `ready`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

let ready = false

// Do database stuff, API stuff, etc.
// Set ready to true when ready

// Temporary / for if someone hits the server before it's finished starting
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(`Loading....`))

app.get('/ping', (req, res) => res.json({ready}))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

### Client

Here we will ping the server every "x" seconds, I set it to 0.5s, once ping returns true, we cancel the timeout and run the initialization code that builds the page.

```
let timeout

timeout = setInterval(async () => {
  let response = await fetch('/ping')
  let ready = await response.json()
  if (ready.ready) {
    clearInterval(timeout)
    loadpage()
  }
}, 500)
```

Comment: Client is a browser. Having a machine so the setInterval rather than a person isn't an answer to the question I am asking.

Comment: OK. If the browser got that from the server, the server has already started.

Comment: No. With the answer I selected the browser will get something different if the server has started.

Comment: Also just because the client gets that from the server, doesn't mean the database/ap/anything has finished connecting or doing what it needs. The routes could have finished being created and the connection could happen x seconds later, so you could still request to `ping` and it would return false.

Comment: Yes, that's the point: the client (ie, a developer's desktop) get 'server still starting' until the server has actually started.